# Detecting floating point software emulation

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

I'm working on an application where runtime speed is more important than precision. The number crunching involves floating point arithmetic and I'm concerned about `double` and/or `long double` being handled in software instead of natively on the processor (this is always true on a 32-bit arch right?). I would like to conditionally compile using the highest precision with hardware support, but I haven't found a quick and easy way to detect software emulation. I'm using g++ on GNU/Linux and I'm not concerned about portability. It's running on x86 arch, so I'm assuming that `float` is always native.

Comment: Why do people have this mystical belief that "float" is native, faster, better?

Comment: @unapersson: The questioner is *9 years* younger than the 8087. It's terrifying.

Comment: @unapersson: because it's true on some architectures, probably (and because it's very commonly the case for integer datatypes)

Comment: @Steve Aye, I remember when I bought (or rather my employer bought me) my first 8087 coprocessor, back when it was a separate chip, and with trembling hands (sure I was going to break the pins of this very expensive item) I inserted it into the copro socket of my IBM XT. It was required for the Lahey F77 compiler, which didn't do FP emulation. Happy days! Of course, I was also living in hole in the motorway at the time.

Comment: @jalf what is commonly the case for integers?

Comment: @unapersson: that wider ones (64-bit ints, typically) aren't natively supported, so they're noticeably slower. So people understandably expect the same to be the case for fp-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Floating-point unit (FPU) on modern x86 is natively double (in fact, it's even bigger than double), not float (the "32" in 32-bit describes the integer register widths, not the floating-point width).  This is not true, however, if your code is taking advantage of vectorized SSE instructions, which do either 4 single or 2 double operations in parallel.

If not, then your main speed hit by switching your app from float to double will be in the increased memory bandwidth.

Answer (score 3):

> (this is always true on a 32-bit arch right?)

No. Common CPU's have dedicated hardware for `double` (and in some cases `long double` as well). And honestly, if performance is a concern, then you should know your CPU. Hit the CPU manuals, and figure out what the performance penalty for each datatype is.

Even on CPUs that lack "proper" `double` support, it still isn't emulated in software. The Cell CPU (of Playstation 3 fame) simply passes a `double` twice through the FPU, so it's a lot costlier than a `float` computation, but it's not software emulation. You still have dedicated instructions for `double` processing. They're just less efficient than the equivalent `float` instructions.

Unless you either target 20-year-old CPU's, or small, limited embedded processors, floating-point instructions will be handled in hardware, although not all architectures handle every datatype equally efficiently

Comment: Anyone care to explain why this was downvoted? Did I say anything that is incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

x86 does `float`, `double`, and more in hardware, and has done for a long time. Many modern 32bit programs assume SSE2 support, as that's been around for several years now and can be depended on to be present on a consumer chip.

Answer (score 1):

On x86, the hardware typically uses 80 bits internally, which is more than enough for double.

Are you sure that performance is a real concern (from profiling the code) or just guessing that it may not be supported?